# Matlab Code for weekdays and weekends

Tags: matlab, simulink

I were able to successfully made a schedule in which the output is 1 if time is between 7 AM-5PM and otherwise 0, time is based on my computer. However the day Monday-Sunday is based on my computer as well.. I cant find the solution to put an output 1 on Monday-Saturday and output 0 on Sunday. The code I have is below

```
function y = IsBetween5AMand7PM
coder.extrinsic('clock');
time = zeros(1,6);
time = clock;
current = 3600*time(4) + 60*time(5) + time(6); %seconds passed from the beginning of day until now
morning = 3600*7; %seconds passed from the beginning of day until 7AM
evening = 3600*17; %seconds passed from the beginning of day until 5PM
y = current > morning && current < evening;

end
```

Now the time here is correct already what I need is for the day (Monday-Sunday) to have my needed output. Also this matlab code is inside a matlab function on Simulink block.

Comment: What version of MATLAB

Comment: See [`weekday`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weekday.html)

Comment: @excaza tried that already but it locates both the weekend (saturday and sunday) whereas what I need is to have sunday alone to have a 0 output.. could you put the code of how will you do it.. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use weekday like this, you can generate a 0/1 value as you specified for today's date:

```
if (weekday(now) > 1)
   day_of_week_flag = 1;
else
   day_of_week_flag = 0;
```

or if you like, this one-liner does the same thing, but may not be as easy to read if you're not familiar with the syntax:

```
day_of_week_flag = ( weekday(now) > 1);
```

You can also use date-strings like this to convert other dates:

```
day_of_week_flag = ( weekday('01-Mar-2016') > 1 )
```

Finally, if you have a numeric array of date/time values, like `[2016 3 3 12 0 0]`, you first need to convert to a serial date using datenum, then use weekday:

```
time = clock;
day_of_week_flag = ( weekday(datenum(time)) > 1);
```

An alternate way to check without using weekday is the following:

```
time = clock;
day_of_week = datestr(time, 8);
if (day_of_week == 'Sun')
   day_of_week_flag = 0;
else
   day_of_week_flag = 1;
```

Comment: I got this error "The function 'weekday' is not supported for standalone code generation. See the documentation for coder.extrinsic to learn how you can use this function in simulation."

Comment: I used the first one

Comment: See updated answer...try `datestr` to see if that is supported.  I don't have the MATLAB compiler on this machine to check...